# Outlook not respecting any kind of width, weather its table or div or img

Tags: outlook

I am trying to force outlook to show my mail in 480px width. 
This works on pretty much every other mail client out there, but not outlook 2016.

I am currently doing this, but cannot come up with any more ways to try.

```
<table width="480" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; width:480px; max-width:480px;">
    <tbody><tr><td>
        <div style="max-width:480px; margin:0 auto;">
            Lots of content here....
        </div></td></tr></tbody></table
```

I also tried putting in an image using style='width:470px;' or the old school width="470".  And Outlook completely ignores it and just show its original size.

Are there any tricks to get around this?

Ok it seems to be photos that are causing the problem here.

If a photo is e.g. 1000px wide, it will make the entire mail 1000px wide, so other than having to rescale every image, is there another way of doing this in outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that width="470" does work, but not when you run it thru Mandrill, then Mandrill is a smart ass and wants to "fix" your HTML and turns width="470" into width="".  So the way to avoid this is to add two of them inside your img tag. So the first one will be "fixed" by mandrill, and the second will be ok and outlook accepts it.